# How to read numeric string as string in sqlite table

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core

I am using **System.Data.SQLite.Core nuget package** in my **asp.net core 3** app.

I have a **SQLite DB** with my table, assuming something like this:

```
+-----+------------+-----+
| ... | Phone      | ... |
+-----+------------+-----+
| --- | 0123456789 | --- |
+-----+------------+-----+
| --- | 9876543210 | --- |
+-----+------------+-----+
```

I do a simple query

```
command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Table", connection);

var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
```

and get data in my reader.
But when I try to Istance the values in an object I can read and cast every value to its type, however I can't cast the phone value into a string (I have declared it as a string in my DB), I mean I can cast it using explicit cast

```
var p = reader[index2];
var t = p.GetType().Name; //--> String
var myobj = new MyObj(othervalues: reader.GetString(index1), phone: (string)reader[index2]);
```

That is working but why can't I simply do this ?

```
... phone: reader.GetString(index2)...
```

And there is a way to do it ?

Thanks for your answer!

**Update:**

[image: Attribute]

Comment: ok but what if I need do in this way ?

Comment: myObject(guid id, string name, string phone, int count)

Comment: Maybe the column is nullable and it's failling to get a specific record with a null value.

Comment: but a phone is not a nuber... if I store smt like `'0215556545'` then when i read it using `GetInt64(index)` i will get `215556545`

Comment: @AndréSanson there is no null value

Comment: So `reader.GetValue(index2).ToString();` doesn't work? Or `reader["yourcolumnname"].ToString()`

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ well yes but no: `GetValue().ToString()` works but as I have already said if I store smt like `'0001'` it returns just `1`

Comment: @RiccardoRaffini it's treating the value as int's then, just use the second one I mention like `reader["yourcolumnname"].ToString()` or `reader[index].ToString()` under the hood (GetValue) it's inferring the type for you, you don't want that.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Yes but I have anyway a problem when I insert into Table value strting with zero

Comment: Can you show the table definition?  It sounds like its defined as an integer in sqlite.

Comment: @haldo I edited question (I am using online browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently change colum definition from `STRING` to `TEXT` seems to work using `reader.GetString(index)` and allows to store phone number like `'0000000001'` too, without deleting zeros.

Comment: Glad you found your solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help